# Is it possible to use an RS232-USB cable (with an FT232RL chip) for RS485-USB communication?

Tags: usb, uart, serial, rs485, rs232

I have a [standard RS232 to USB cable found on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0759HSLP1).

It does not work out of the box. This is what I expect since RS232 uses a ground reference and RS485 uses a differential between the two data lines and requires termination resistors. However, there seems to be information on the internet that suggests that the [FT232RL](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT232R.pdf) could work with RS485 (although no proof of it working).

Is there a way to make the cable work with RS485 either by configuring the FTDI chip somehow and/or modifying the cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FT232R itself does support RS485, but it must be configured to do so with FTDI's FT_PROG tool, and it requires a different circuit layout than RS232.

You can find information about this in [the datasheet](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT232R.pdf). The configuration is described in section 3.5 - CBUS Signal Options. The RS232 application example (7.1) shows how the cable is likely to currently be wired. The RS485 application example (7.2) shows how the circuit would have to look in order to support RS485.

You would need to open the cable housing and find the PCB with the chip on it, bodge the CBUS2, CBUS3, TXD, and RXD pins onto an RS485 level converter such as the SP481 shown in the application example, cutting the existing TXD/RXD lines, then reconnect the level converter outputs to the connector.

It's probably way cheaper and easier to just buy an RS485 cable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can modify it by removing RS-232 PHY and replacing it with RS-485 PHY.

Or using a RS-232 to RS-485 converter.

Not worth it though as you can simply buy a proper USB to RS-485 adapter.

Comment: @user-2147482038 "PHY" is shorthand for Physical Layer; in this context it would mean a transceiver chip.